# Search data from multiple tables using sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In mysql Database I've following tables and html search form. Now I want to search selected data **(From Search Form)** from multiple tables. Selected data could be `gender`, `budget`or `location`. For location I've 7 tables. **(No. 2-8)** and each 7 tables second column value could be `0` OR  `1` when user signup as there Location.So in this Location field user can select Central or East Or West or...others when searching.

So how do I write a sql query ( or Sql Join Query) to get the result from Mysql tables for search ?

**Php Variable :**

```
$gender = inputvalid($_POST['gender']);
$budget = inputvalid($_POST['budget']);
$location = inputvalid($_POST['location']);
```

**Table name with column name**

```
1. tutor_signup_form        (tutor_id, gender, feerange, name, email)
2. tutor_signup_pre_central (tutor_id, pre_c_central, place1, place2, place3)
3. tutor_signup_pre_west    (tutor_id, pre_w_west, place1, place2, place3)
4. tutor_signup_pre_east    (tutor_id, pre_e_east, place1, place2, place3)
5. tutor_signup_pre_south   (tutor_id, pre_s_south, place1, place2, place3)
6. tutor_signup_pre_north   (tutor_id, pre_n_north, place1, place2, place3)
7. tutor_signup_pre_ne      (tutor_id, pre_ne_northEast, place1, place2, place3)
8. tutor_signup_pre_nw      (tutor_id, pre_nw_northWest, place1, place2, place3)
```

**and I've a search form is look like this:**

```
<tr>
    <td style="width:100px;">1. Gender:</td>
    <td>    
        <select name="gender">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="male">Male only</option>
        <option value="female">Female only</option>
        </select>
    </td>   
    </tr>
<tr>
    <td>2. Budget:</td>
    <td>
        <select name="budget">
        <option value="" SELECTED>--Select--</option>
        <option value="90">$90 and below</option>
        <option value="80">$80 and below</option>
        <option value="70">$70 and below</option>
        <option value="60">$60 and below</option>
        <option value="50">$50 and below</option>
        <option value="40">$40 and below</option>
        <option value="30">$30 and below</option>
        <option value="25">$25 and below</option>
        <option value="20">$20 and below</option>
        <option value="15">$15 and below</option>
        <option value="10">$10 and below</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3. Location:</td>
    <td>
    <select name='location'>
    <option value="" SELECTED>--Select--.</option>
    <option value='1' />Central City</option>
    <option value='2' />East City</option>
    <option value='3' />West City   </option>
    <option value='4' />South City  </option>
    <option value='5' />North City  </option>
    <option value='6' />North East  </option>
    <option value='7' />North West  </option>       
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this: **EDITED**

```
  if($location == '1'){
    $tableName="tutor_signup_pre_central";
    }
    if($location == '2'){
    $tableName="tutor_signup_pre_west";
    }
```

same for other table also..then sql.

```
$sql = "select tutor_signup_form.*,$tableName.place1,$tableName.place2,$tableName.place3 from  tutor_signup_form left join $tableName on tutor_signup_form.tutor_id = $tableName.tutor_id where tutor_signup_form.gender= $gender and tutor_signup_form.feerange=$budget";
```

can use some modifications if required.

Comment: what is the value of `$table ?`

Comment: sorry but it should be $tableName which is used every where.

Comment: i have changed the sql now see.

Comment: i'll suggest you to change your database structure. maybe convert your table to one in which add location,place1,place2,place3 where location   will refer to pre_c_central and other respective values.

Comment: Yes, you are right but In each location I've 24 place. 7*24 = total 168  column. is it right way..

Comment: if you are getting any error please put the error in comment.

Comment: In you sql query where is the $location ?

Comment: using $location only you are getting table name what else you want to do with $location.

Answer (score 0):

It should be purpose for searching data and You must be use myisam engine.

Your database design is too normalization.(No. 2-8) and each 7 tables have same column set.

You can merge as single database like 
**tutor_signup_form        (tutor_id, gender, feerange, name, email,location, place1, place2, place3).**

You write query like **select * from tutor_signup_form where gender='' or budget ='' or location =''**. whatever condition need.